# How to define the enum incrementation step?

Tags: c, enums

I wan to define enum with non constant step. I want that the step between 2 enum variables looks like that:

```
enum test {
   a1 = 1,
   a2 = 1<<2,
   a3 = 1<<3,
   a4, // a4 deduced automatically as 1<<4
   a5 // a5 deduced automatically as 1<<5
}
```

Are there a way to define it as indicated in the above example?

Comment: C is a pretty simple language, I don't think it has any features that try to extrapolate from examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do this manually, or possibly with macro chicanery.

Answer (score 2):

this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define enum_(x, n) x##n=1<<n

enum type {
    enum_(a, 0),
    enum_(a, 1),
    enum_(a, 2),
    enum_(a, 3),
    enum_(a, 4),
    enum_(a, 5)
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no assignemt for enum members,

- Then zero will be considered for the first enum member.
- For other members, it will just use the previous member`s value by adding one
  on it.

More over in your program assignment (`=`) operator is not used in enum definition. It should be like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum test 
{
   a1 = 1,
   a2 = 1<<2,
   a3 = 1<<3,
   a4, // a4 deduced automatically as 1<<4
   a5 // a5 deduced automatically as 1<<5
};

void main()
{
   printf("%d, %d", a4, a5);
}
```

output is

```
9, 10
```